# Im solving a statistic problem using R and I need help regarding confidence interval for the population mean difference

Tags: r

[image]

```
> be = c(81.6, 88.5, 80.3, 100.2, 94.3, 90.3)
> af = c(83.0, 84.8, 73.0, 92.5, 89.4, 85.7)
> t.test(be, af, alternative = "two.sided", mu = 0, conf.level = 0.99)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  be and af
t = 1.084, df = 9.8542, p-value = 0.3042
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
99 percent confidence interval:
 -8.636224 17.569557
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 89.20000  84.73333
```

So i've obtained the **p-value = 0.3042** which is greater than **α = 0.01**, hence i'll reject H1 and the answer for (b) will be **"12-week special exercise program do not reduce weight"**

But how should i answer for (a) ?

Comment: Since you have a before and after, this is a prefect example for a matched pair t-test.

Comment: @Dave2e u mean the code should be ```t.test(be, af, alternative = "two.sided", paired = T, mu = 0, conf.level = 0.99)``` ?

Comment: Yes, now you are testing if the change in weight is zero.   Your first test was testing if the weight of population was different pre and post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answering part b, you should have firstly performed a Shapiro-Wilks test to determine if the difference in weigths are Normally distributed.

Secondly, your use of the t-test function is incorrect. You should have applied a paired t-test.

```
>t.test(be,af,paired = TRUE,conf.level = 0.99)

    Paired t-test

data:  be and af
t = 3.3388, df = 5, p-value = 0.02058
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
99 percent confidence interval:
 -0.9276381  9.8609714
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
               4.466667
```

This output shows the p-value of 0.02 which means you reject the null-hypothesis of no effect. (Intuitively, the results do show a material weight drop in 4 out of 5 cases)

for part a of your question, the 99% confidence interval is given in the output you provided above: (-0.92,9.87).

You can also confirm this using the CI function Rmisc package or calculate on your own. See code below.

```
dif<-be-af

library(Rmisc)
CI(dif,0.99)

#Calculate limits

mean(dif)
s<-sd(dif)
n<-length(dif)

error <- qt(0.995,df=n-1)*s/sqrt(n)

mean(dif)-error #Lower Limit
mean(dif)+error #Upper Limit
```

Ref: https://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/confidence.html#calculating-a-confidence-interval-from-a-normal-distribution

Answer (score 0):

You include the answer to A as part of your question!

```
99 percent confidence interval:
 -8.636224 17.569557
```

To be clear though, you won't reject H1, *you'll fail to reject H0*. The reason behind this phrasing is that perhaps with another set of data you might find a different result. Hope this helps.

Comment: so the answer for (a) will be "-8.636224" and "17.569557" is it?

Comment: Yes -- make sure to fix your function to not include the mu argument, and the outputting two numbers will be your lower and upper bound respectively